# Implementing a Recursive Function to Generate Fibonacci Series in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, optimization

I need assistance in designing a recursive Python function to generate the Fibonacci series up to a given number of terms. While attempting this, I faced challenges in optimizing the recursive algorithm without encountering stack overflow errors.

"Looking for guidance in implementing an optimized recursive Python function to generate the Fibonacci series efficiently without encountering recursion depth issues."

Comment: FYI even though this was closed as duplicate, it's not a duplicate. You haven't shown any effort of your own - you only posted your assignment. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Also read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)